# How can I make a Grid that has tab stopping behavior?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, focus

I created a simple WPF `UserControl` that has a `Grid` as its `Content` control that reacts to `MouseEnter`, `MouseLeave`, and `MouseDown` events. Basically it is behaving like a button at this point, changing color when hovered and doing something when clicked.

I want this control to also implement tab stopping and get focus when tabbing though the controls. I tried setting `IsTabStop` on the containing `UserControl`, but that didn't seem to do anything.

Also, while the `UserControl.Content` is a `Grid`, the `Grid` can also have `Children` added to it, but I want that root `Grid` to be what gets tab stopped.

Any ideas how I can implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UserControl.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp1.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             Width="100" Height="100" Focusable="False">
    <Grid x:Name="grid" Background="Black" Focusable="True"
          MouseEnter="Grid_MouseEnter"
          MouseLeave="Grid_MouseLeave"
          MouseDown="Grid_MouseDown"
          GotFocus="Grid_GotFocus">
        <TextBlock Text="UserControlButton?" Foreground="White"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**UserControl.cs**

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        grid.FocusVisualStyle = null;
    }
    // hover
    private void Grid_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) => grid.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    private void Grid_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) => grid.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);

    private void Grid_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) => grid.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);

    // tabstop
    private void Grid_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => grid.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);

    
    private void grid_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, got this working based no your answer!

Answer (score 1):

The `Grid` has its [`Focusable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.focusable?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) property set to `false` by default, so it will not receive focus of any kind.

> Gets or sets a value that indicates whether the element can receive focus.
>
> When deriving from UIElement directly (as opposed to from Control), consider whether you wish your element to be focusable, because by default the element will not be focusable.

If you set it to `true`, it will automatically participate in tabbing.

```
<Grid Focusable="True" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="None"  Background="Yellow">
```

If you only want the `Grid` to be a tab stop, but not its children, set the [`TabNavigation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.keyboardnavigation.tabnavigation?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) property to [`None`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.keyboardnavigationmode?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#system-windows-input-keyboardnavigationmode-cycle).

> No keyboard navigation is allowed inside this container.

```
<Grid Focusable="True" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="None"  Background="Yellow">
```

Comment: Thanks for this info! I am experimenting with it now.